# httpclient post xml content in java

Tags: java, xml, apache-commons-httpclient

I am trying to use httpclient to post xml request as following:

```
String parm1 = MyXml.toString();
PostMethod post = new Postmethod(url);
post.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(parm1));
...
```

I have an object in the program which I want to convert it to xml representation.

My question is that what is the best way to create Myxml in xml format in java which then I can simply print out its String format later.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking for the best way to create a `toXML()` method or are you asking something about the technique for POSTing data?

Comment: I am more interested in creating a xml that later I can use it to pass in parameter for the http post.  So, I guess I am kinda asking both.

Comment: you could look at http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-xml-tutorials/ for the XML part.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options for creating XML in Java. This answer [How to serialize and de-serialize objects using JAXB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189690/how-to-serialize-and-de-serialize-objects-using-jaxb) provides a good demo of one common way that seems to fit your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can post xml request using **Apache HttpClient.**

- Use apache Velocity to create the request xml format
- Use Castor to convert response stream( respReader ) into java object

  ```
  final String request = createXmlRequest(); // helper method to create the xml request
  final HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  final PostMethod post = new PostMehod(url); // url - www.google.cm/someoperaion

  post.setRequestHeader("Content-Language", "en-US");
  post.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(request, "text/xml", "ISO-8859-1"));

  final int returnCode = client.executeMethod(post);

  final BufferedReader respReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(post.getResponseBodyAsStream()));
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use it this way...

```
public void postData() throws Exception {


 HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://www.xyz.com");

 List<NameValuePair> list = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

 list.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name","ABC");

 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(list));

 HttpResponse r = client.execute(httppost);

}
```