# XmlRpcClient parse response with multiple Variable types

Tags: java, xml-parsing, xml-rpc, xmlrpcclient

I'm using XmlRpcClient to connect to a XML-RPC server
In the response to my request in the XML response I will get:

```
int cpuLoad, 
String fanStatus, 
String fanStatusWorst, 
String temperatureStatus, 
String temperatureStatusWorst,
String rtcBatteryStatus,
String rtcBatteryStatusWorst, 
String voltagesStatus, 
String voltagesStatusWorst, 
String operationalStatus
```

I'm using

```
HashMap result = (HashMap) xmlRpcClient.execute(METHOD_DEVICE_HEALTH, params );
```

to retrieve results, but not sure how can I iterate over each value to 
find operationalStatus value.
Is there a more elegant solution to parse results using xmlRpcClient? So I just retrieve the fields I'm interested?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there are more than one answer to your question depending on your cenario.

```
1) If you are communicating with Java based system using XML-RPC
```

Apache XML-RPC library comes with handy class called `ClientFactory`. This class allows you to bind your service interface (in your case the interface of the object you are invoking `METHOD_DEVICE_HEALTH`) to an object in the JVM of your consumer (the object that invokes `xmlRpcClient.execute(METHOD_DEVICE_HEALTH, params)`). For more details about the implementation, take a look at [this link](http://ws.apache.org/xmlrpc/advanced.html).

In this cenario, you can even have an transfert object like

```
public class DeviceHealth {
  int cpuLoad, 
  String fanStatus, 
  String fanStatusWorst, 
  String temperatureStatus, 
  String temperatureStatusWorst,
  String rtcBatteryStatus,
  String rtcBatteryStatusWorst, 
  String voltagesStatus, 
  String voltagesStatusWorst, 
  String operationalStatus

  // getters and setters
}
```

and a method in your service class returning directly its type

```
public interface HealthService {
   DeviceHealth checkDeviceHealth(int id);
}

public class DefaultHealthService implements HealthService {
    public DeviceHealth checkDeviceHealth(int id) {}
}
```

The framework will serialize and deserialize this object automatically for you.

```
2) If you are communicating with other systems
```

Well, in this case your gona have to handle the serialization and deserialization process your own. You can use for that JAXB, which has a reference implementation built-in JDK 1.6 and 1.7. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189690/how-to-serialize-and-de-serialize-objects-using-jaxb) gives you an idea on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks Trein, will use option 2